# Ways in which 38 can be divided into 3 positive parts such that the first is divisible by 8, the second by 7 and the third part by 3?

Tags: combinatorics

I am stuck with the question, i have tried a couple of random approaches but none of them is correct. The answer is 2. Please help if you know how to solve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that second and third part should both be either even or odd, number of possibilities are reduced very much. For first part =8, 21,  9 are the solution.
For first part= 16, 7, 15 are the solution

Comment: it was in the comments ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each part must be an integer, this is equivalent to the number of non negative integral solutions of
$$8x+7y+3z=38$$

We have $x,y,z\ge1$. So, let $a=x-1,b=y-1,c=z-1$ such that $a,b,c\ge0$.
Then,
$$8a-8+7b-7+3c-3=38$$
$$8a+7b+3c=56$$
Let $X=8a,Y=7b,Z=3c$.
$$X+Y+Z=56$$
Allowed values of $X=0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56$.

Allowed values of $Y=0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56$.

Allowed values of $Z=0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54$.

Number of solutions=Coefficient of $x^{56}$ in the expansion of
$$(1+x^8+x^{16}+\cdots+x^{56})(1+x^7+x^{14}+\cdots+x^{56})(1+x^{3}+x^6+\cdots+x^{54})$$
that is coefficient of $x^{56}$ in
$$\left(\frac{1-x^{64}}{1-x^8}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^{63}}{1-x^7}\right)\left(\frac{1-x^{57}}{1-x^3}\right)$$

which can be further simplified using binomial expansions.

Using this, you can find all possible solutions in general. In this case, however, trial and error may be more convenient.

Comment: The title says Positive Parts.

Comment: @barakmanos I have answered keeping that in mind. Assumed integers though

Comment: Of course integers, otherwise the word *divisible* is meaningless. However, you denote $X=8a$ (for example), hence if $X=0$ then so is the "$8a$" part of $38$.

Comment: @barakmanos I relabelled $x,y,z$ as $a,b,c$ such that $a,b,c\ge0$. The sum is now $56$, not $38$. So $a=0$ is allowed. I agree it was unnecessary, initially I thought it might simplify things

Comment: I think it would be best if you simply showed all the solutions, there aren't too many of them anyway, and that will definitely clarify whatever's left for doubt...

Comment: ( 2,1,3) and ( 1,3,3) ? I stopped to answer because it is allmost a simple enumeration of the cases starting from the possible values to take from { 1,2,3 } X { 1,2,3,4 } X { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 }

Comment: $38=8+21+9$, first is a multiple of 8, 2nd term a multiple of 7, and  the final one a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

We want $8A + 7B + 3C = 38;A,B,C \ge 1$

Method 1:

Note: $8 = 2*7 - 2*3$ and $3*7 = 7*3$

So if $8A + 7B + 3C = 38$ is a solution.  So is $8(A\pm1) + 7(B\pm 2)+ 3(C\mp 2)=38$.  And so is $8A + 7(B\pm 3) + 3(C\mp 7)=38$.

From this if we get one solution we can tweak it to get all solutions, even if our first solution was out of range.

$8*0 + 7*5 + 3*1 = 38$.  But that can't be a solution because $A= 0 < 1$.

So we tweak it.  $8*1 + 7*(5-2) + 3*(1 + 2) = 8*1 + 7*3 + 3*3=38$ is a legitimate solution.  $(8,21,9)$ is first solution.

To find all others with fixed $A=1$ we tweak $8*1 + 7(3 \pm 3k) + 3(3 \mp 7k)=38$.  However it is impossible for $k \ne 0$ for $3 \pm 3k$ and $3 \mp 7k$ to both be positive.  So $(8,21,9)$ is the only solution with $A = 1$.

Teak $A = 2$ to get $8*2 + 7*(3-2) + 3(3+2)= 8*2 + 7*1 + 3*5=16 + 7 + 15=38$ to get our second solution $(16,7,15)$.

If we fix $A = 2$ we get $8*2 + 7(1 \pm 3k) + 3(5 \mp 7k)$.  Again there are no values other than $k = 0$ to get a legitimate answer in range where both the $7$ and $3$ coefficients are both positive.

Tweak $A = 3$ to get $8*3 + 7*(-1) + 3*7 = 38$.  The 7 coefficient is out of range but we can tweak it to get $8*3 + 7*2 + 3*0 = 38$.  But now the 3 coefficient is out of range.  So there are no $8*3 + 7(-1+3k) + 3(7 - 7k)=38$ solution in range.

And likewise is $A \ge 4$ it's worse.  If $8*A \ge 32$ then $7B + 3C \le 6$ which is clearly impossible if $B, C \ge 1$.

So the only solutions are $(8,21,9)$ and $(16,7, 15)$.

Method 2.

$8A + 7B + 3C = 38;A,B,C \ge 1$

$8A = 38 - 7B - 3c \ge 38 - 7 - 3 = 28$

so $A \le 3$.

$8A + 7B + 3C = 38 \equiv 3 \mod 7$

$A + 3C \equiv 3 \mod 7$

So $3C = 7k - A + 3$ for some $k$.  $k \equiv A \mod 3$ and $(7k - A +3)\ge 3$ so $k \ge A/7$

$8A + 7B + 3C \equiv -1 \mod 3$ so

$-A + B \equiv -1 \mod 3$ so $B = 3j + A - 1$.  $3j + A - 1 \ge 1$ so $j \ge (2-A)/3$.

So $8A + 7(3j + A - 1) + (7k - A +3) = 38$

$14A + 21j + 7k = 42$

So...........

Solve for: **$2A + 3j + k = 6; 1 \le A \le 3; j \ge (2-A)/3; k \ge A/7; k \equiv A \mod 3$**.

......

If $A = 1;$

$3j + k = 4$

$j\ge 1; k \ge 1; k \equiv 1 \mod 3$. If $k \ge 4$ then $j \le 0$.  So   $k=1; j = 1; B =3; C =3$ is only solution. i.e. $(8, 21, 9)$.

If $A = 2;$

$3j + k = 2$

$j\ge 0; k \ge 2; k \equiv 2 \mod 3$.
 so $k = 2;j=0; B= 1; C = 5$ is only solution i.e. $(16,7,15)$.

If $A = 3;$
$3j + k = 0$

$j \ge 0; k \ge 1; k \equiv 3 \mod 3;$ and $3j + k = 0$ which has no solutions.